# Exclude extension h from Asterisk pattern

Tags: asterisk

in my dialplan for Asterisk 12.4.0, I would like to accept both numeric and string extens, so that I use something like this:

```
[trunks]
exten => _[*#0-9a-z]!,1,Verbose(Incoming call)
exten => _[*#0-9a-z]!,n,Verbose(Incoming call - other processing 0)
exten => _[*#0-9a-z]!,n,Verbose(Incoming call - other processing 1)
exten => _[*#0-9a-z]!,n,Verbose(Incoming call - other processing 2)
exten => _[*#0-9a-z]!,n,Verbose(Incoming call - other processing 3)
exten => h,1,NoOp()
exten => t,1,Hangup()
exten => i,1,Hangup()
exten => s,1,Hangup()
```

Unfortunately, there is a mechanism mentioned [here](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Pattern+Matching) (red box with title "Be Careful with Pattern Matching") which causes that extension h (called automatically on Hangup) executes also lines with
Incoming call - other processing 0-3.

Output of asterisk -rvvv when dialing 123 is:

```
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Executing [123@trunks:1] Verbose("SIP/trunk_audio2redil-00000008", "Incoming call") in new stack
Incoming call
    -- Executing [123@trunks:2] Verbose("SIP/trunk_audio2redil-00000008", "Incoming call - other processing 0") in new stack
Incoming call - other processing 0
    -- Executing [123@trunks:3] Verbose("SIP/trunk_audio2redil-00000008", "Incoming call - other processing 1") in new stack
Incoming call - other processing 1
    -- Executing [123@trunks:4] Verbose("SIP/trunk_audio2redil-00000008", "Incoming call - other processing 2") in new stack
Incoming call - other processing 2
    -- Executing [123@trunks:5] Verbose("SIP/trunk_audio2redil-00000008", "Incoming call - other processing 3") in new stack
Incoming call - other processing 3
    -- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/trunk_audio2redil-00000008' status is 'UNKNOWN'
    -- Executing [h@trunks:1] NoOp("SIP/trunk_audio2redil-00000008", "") in new stack
    -- Executing [h@trunks:2] Verbose("SIP/trunk_audio2redil-00000008", "Incoming call - other processing 0") in new stack
Incoming call - other processing 0
    -- Executing [h@trunks:3] Verbose("SIP/trunk_audio2redil-00000008", "Incoming call - other processing 1") in new stack
Incoming call - other processing 1
    -- Executing [h@trunks:4] Verbose("SIP/trunk_audio2redil-00000008", "Incoming call - other processing 2") in new stack
Incoming call - other processing 2
    -- Executing [h@trunks:5] Verbose("SIP/trunk_audio2redil-00000008", "Incoming call - other processing 3") in new stack
Incoming call - other processing 3
```

**I'd like the processing to stop after line**

```
-- Executing [h@trunks:1] NoOp("SIP/trunk_audio2redil-00000008", "") in new stack
```

but I don't know how to do it.

My ideas how this could be achieved:

- To disable the "fallthrough" mechanism, but I don't know how and if it is possible.
- Modify the pattern so that it would match all numbers (including single-digit ones) and all strings longer than 1. Again I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Way

```
exten => _[*#0-9a-g,j-r,u-z]!,1,Verbose(Incoming call)
```

Context way(matching priority):

```
[trunks]
include=>trunks_pattern
exten => h,1,NoOp()
exten => t,1,Hangup()
exten => i,1,Hangup()
exten => s,1,Hangup()
[trunks_pattern]
exten => _[*#0-9a-z]!,1,Verbose(Incoming call)
exten => _[*#0-9a-z]!,n,Verbose(Incoming call - other processing 0)
exten => _[*#0-9a-z]!,n,Verbose(Incoming call - other processing 1)
exten => _[*#0-9a-z]!,n,Verbose(Incoming call - other processing 2)
exten => _[*#0-9a-z]!,n,Verbose(Incoming call - other processing 3)
```

Last based on: included context will be matched only if no match in this context and in EXACT order of including.

Also will work like this

```
exten => _.,1,Verbose(incoming call)
exten => h,1,Verbose(hangup)
```

That should **not** work, but work on all current asterisk versions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use the "simple way", because the pattern doesn't accept any EXTEN beginning with h,i,s,t.

Comment: add enother rule [*#0-9a-z] in front.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way similar to the "context way" suggested by arheops:

```
[trunks]
exten => _[*#0-9a-z]!,1,Verbose(Incoming call)
exten => _[*#0-9a-z]!,n,Verbose(Incoming call - other processing 0)
exten => _[*#0-9a-z]!,n,Verbose(Incoming call - other processing 1)
exten => _[*#0-9a-z]!,n,Verbose(Incoming call - other processing 2)
exten => _[*#0-9a-z]!,n,Verbose(Incoming call - other processing 3)

exten => h,1,Goto(hangup,h,1)
exten => t,1,Hangup()
exten => i,1,Hangup()
exten => s,1,Hangup()

[hangup]
exten => h,1,NoOp()
```

Comment: lol. if that ok for you, just put h,1,Hangup. That is enought